# .NET equivalent to Java thread groups?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm trying to monitor the states of a group of threads in a Microsoft.NET application written in C#. I'd like to be able to also monitor any child threads spawned by the original threads.

In Java, you can assign threads to a thread group, and their children will also belong to the group. Is there an equivalent in .NET?

I briefly looked at ExecutionContext and LogicalCallContext, but I can't see how to find all the threads that are in a context. Raymond Chen has an article about a [Win32 API method](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/02/23/537856.aspx) for enumerating threads, but I hope I don't have to go that low.

Answer (score 3):

You can enumerate the threads in your process using the [Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process.threads(VS.80).aspx) property of System.Diagnostics.Process.

Note however, that the objects you get here are not of the same type as those you create to start threads yourself (i.e. are not System.Threading.Thread objects).

A concept of thread groups does not exist however, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

They are working on something like that in their "Task" API, which is part of Parallel Extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple:

Create your ThreadGroup class with a method wrapping the thread creation process.

When this method is called, it adds the created thread to a Collection and there is your group.

Comment: That's a good idea if you control all the code that's launching threads, but I don't.